# XSD element data duplication

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.0

I have an XSD and XML files that works 90% and is almost completed. 
For example, if I have this XML document.

```
<Family>
    <Family_Client>
        <ClientID>1234</ClientID>
    </Family_Client>
    <Loan>
        <Family_Client>
            <ClientID>1234</ClientID>
        </Family_Client>
    </Loan>
</Family>
```

Is it possible to manipulate the XSD (XML Schema) to make sure that the `ClientID` in loan is the same as the `clientID` above in `Family_Client`?

Also, if there are multiple `Family_Clients`, I want the `Family_Client` in `Loan` to also be the same. So example of this would be:

```
<Family>
    <Family_Client>
        <ClientID>1234</ClientID>
    </Family_Client>
    <Family_Client>
        <ClientID>2345</ClientID>
    </Family_Client>
    <Loan>
        <Family_Client>
            <ClientID>1234</ClientID>
        </Family_Client>
        <Family_Client>
            <ClientID>2345</ClientID>
        </Family_Client>
    </Loan>
</Family>
```

Comment: Which version of XSD? If 1.0 probably not.  If 1.1 (which isn't widely supported) then yes.

Comment: i am using xml version 1.0

Comment: Then you would have to do that validation outside of the schema or change the structure of your schema & XML so you don't have this duplication

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend changing the structure of your schema.

If each loan only belongs to a single family client then you should put it under that node.  If you want to have multiple loans per client, put them under a Loans node

```
<Family>
    <Family_Client>
        <ClientID>1234</ClientID>
        <Loans>
            <Loan>
                   <!-- details of loan here -->
            </Loan>    
            <Loan>
                   <!-- details of loan here -->
            </Loan>    
        </Loans>
    </Family_Client>
</Family>
```

Comment: Even if XSD 1.1 were an option, this solution would still be prefered.  (+1)

Comment: unfortunately our database assigns Loans to Family, not Family_Client. So, as much as i would love to switch it around and make it work like this, it won't properly align with our database if i do it this way.

Comment: But you should still be able to express that structure in your schema unless it is a many to many relationship.